# Define $T:P(R) \Rightarrow P(R)$ by $T(f(x))= \int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt$, where $P(F)$ is the set of polynomials with coefficients from Field.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Define $T:P(R) \Rightarrow P(R)$ by $T(f(x))= \int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt$, where $P(F)$ is the set of polynomials with coefficients from Field.

Prove that T is one-to-one, but not onto.

I am not sure how to prove the onto part. I was given a hint that T is onto if every element of codomain has a preimage. I am not sure how to go on constructing at least one codomain doesn't have a preimage. Any help?

Comment: showing that $T$ is not onto is equivalent to show that the derivative operator is not injective in the polynomial ring, and this is related to the limit of zero in the definition of the integral, by example note that $3x$ and $3x+1$ have the same derivative, therefore one of the polynomials is not in the range of $T$

Comment: What is the degree of $T(f)$ if $f$ has degree $n$?

Comment: @ArcticChar n since it's $P(R) \Rightarrow P(R)$?

Comment: Ar.. no, what is the degree of $T(f)$ when $f(x)  =x$?

Comment: @ArcticChar so it's 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is $T(f(x))(0)$? Then provide an example of a polynomial that doesn't have this property.